# No muestra decimales Double C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un código como el siguiente

```
double res = 10/3;
```

y al momento de inspeccionar el valor de la variable res
me muestra 3. Cual sea la operación, siempre me redondea el resultado.

¿Hay alguna forma que me muestre los decimales?

Comment: Divide 10.0/3.0 el problema es que una división de enteros produce un resultado entero.

Comment: Entonces siempre debo de convertir los enteros a double para que doubles entre doubles resulte otro double?

Comment: Sí, o sino, guarda los valores en variables de tipo double. double a = 10; double b = 3;. Basta con que un valor sea double para que el resultado sea double.

Comment: Muchas gracias sin duda esto resolvió el problema, sos un crack

Comment: @crrlos lo pones como respuesta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > No muestra decimales Double C#

```
double res = 10/3;
```

El problema de ese código, es que el compilador implícitamente (el lo hace, tu no) toma el resultado de la expresión `10/3` como tipo `integer`.

Si quieres que no sea así, debes decirle explicitamente (o sea, tú) al compilador que el resultado de esa expresión debe ser de tipo `double`.

```
double res = (double)10 / 3;
```

Para más información: [Casting and type conversions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)